# Change custom class square brackets returning value

Tags: c#, class, dictionary, brackets, square

I have a class Locale that contains a public Dictionary named Values.
What I want is :

```
Locale l = new Locale(.....);
// execute stuff that loads the Values dictionary...
// currently to get the values in it I have to write :
string value = l.Values["TheKey"];
// What I want is to be able to get the same thing using :
string value = l["TheKey"];
```

I want basically to change the returned value when using square brackets with a custom class.

Comment: You can create an `Indexed Property` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/aa288464(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: It's called [Indexer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx) in C#.

Comment: @Handoko.Chen Yes! Right.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, you can implement an `indexer` for your class `Locale`.

Example

```
public class Locale
{
    Dictionary<string, string> _dict;
    public Locale()
    {
        _dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        _dict.Add("dot", "net");
        _dict.Add("java", "script");
    }
    public string this[string key] //this is the indexer
    {
        get
        {
            return _dict[key];
        }
        set //remove setter if you do not need
        {
            _dict[key] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var l = new Locale();
var value = l["java"]; //"script"
```

Here is the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx) reference.

Comment: @Simon56 you can accept the answer if it solved your problem :)

Comment: He've actually never accepted it...